# iPhone + UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having UITableView in my application, I want to do formatting of it, like change the height of rows in table, change the font and colors of text in cells etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should read [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) in Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views).

**Changing the Text Colour and Font**

If you're using a standard table view cell, you can customise the text colour and font of its `textLabel` (or `detailLabel`) label in the [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview?language=objc) data source method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* Cell initialisation code... */
    /* Configure Cell */
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:22]];
    return cell;
}
```

**Changing the Height of a Row**

If every row is going to be the same height, you should set the `rowHeight` property of your `UITableView`:

```
[tableView setRowHeight:42];
```

If the rows are going to have variable heights, then you can use the [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc) delegate method of `UITableView`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat height = 42;
    if ([indexPath row] == 4) {
        height = 21;
    }
    return height;
}
```

If you want to completely change the look of your table view cells, you might want to look at Matt Gallagher's [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) article, as suggested by @mfu. However, make sure you know exactly what you're doing if you start going this far—most of the time you will want to stick to Apple's default styles.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at subclassing [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell) and with that new subclass you can have anything you want inside the cell - other views, buttons, labels, etc.

Apple has many good samples of this.  See [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell) for a list of samples.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather general.
You can refer to very nice article here to get some basic idea on how you can write custom table view ['easy custom uitableview drawing'](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)